# Convergence of Markov chain and stationary distribution..but some TM don't converge...

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

THEOREM:

Let $\{X_n, ~ n\le 0\}$ be a regular homogenous finite-state Markov Chain with transition matrix P with state space $E=\{0,1, \cdots, m\}$.  Then:

$$\lim \limits_{p \to \infty} P^n = \hat{P}$$

where $\hat{P}$ is a matrix whoese rows are identical and equal to the stationary distribution $x_n = (\Pr(X_n=0), \Pr(X_n=1), \cdots, \Pr(X_n=m))$ for the Markov chain defined by:

$$\hat{x}P = \hat{x}$$

---

What I don't understand... there are some Markov chains where $P^n$ doesn't converge to a matrix with constant values.  therefore it has no limit.  How can this theorem above be true?  Example:

Given transition matrix:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

then:

$$P^n = \begin{cases}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} & n=1,3,5, \cdots \\ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} & n=2,4, 6, \cdots\end{cases}$$

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} P^n = \text{doesn't exist}$$

However it has a stationary distribution:

$$\hat{x} = \begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix}$$

according to the theorem $P^n$ should be create by concatenating rows of the stationary distribution with itself to create a matrix of constant values....

Comment: There are also some missing hypotheses in your theorem statement.  For instance, some MC transition matrices have more than one stationary distribution; for such chains your theorem is also absurd.

Comment: I found another source that says that there needs to be some power of $P^n$  where all elements of the matrix are non-zero in order for the Markov chain to be considered a "regular".  So I guess that part is ok...

Comment: On first reading I skipped the word "regular".  Your result follows from the [Perron-Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) theorem.